# Jquery toggle animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make my div toggle between it's positions with this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
   $("div").animate({left:'250px'};
 },
 function() {
  $("div").animate({left:'0px'};
 },
});
```

All I need it to do is to left: "250px" the div, then when the button is clicked again, move it back to left: "0px".
All answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

click doesn't work that way, it only has one callback, but you can toggle the animation with a flag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var l = $(this).data('l');
        $("div").animate({left: (l ?  0 : 250)});
        $(this).data('l', !l);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QHtNL/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it. I would add a class to the div to track its state.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('open') {
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $("div").animate({left:'250px'});
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
            $("div").animate({left:'0px'});
        }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off just adding a class that does the moving... It's more efficient and easier to control than the jQuery `animate()` alternative.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        $('div').toggleClass('move');
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
}

div.move {
    left: 250px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ab5s/1/)**